# PHP - prepared statement returns error: column 'name' can not be null

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm new to prepared statements and I have following code in place. It takes a csv file from user and imports it into the database. For some unexplainable reason I'm getting an error `column 'name' can not be empty` which means variable `$line[0]` is null, but when I output it, I'm getting the right value.

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

$insertProductQ = "INSERT INTO products (name, category_id, brand_id, bar_code, gross_weight, less_weight, net_weight, selling_purity, labor_cost, quantity, min_order, purity, design, origin, description, status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$insertProduct = $conn->prepare($insertProductQ);

@$insertProduct->bind_param('ssisddddiiiiiisi', $line[0], $line[1], $brands[$line[10]], $line[2], $line[3], $line[4], $line[5], $line[6], $line[7], $line[8], $line[9], $purity[$line[11]], $design[$line[12]], $origin[$line[13]], $line[14], $line[15]);

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($line[0]);

    $exec = $insertProduct->execute();
    if($exec === FALSE){
        $_SESSION['msg']['type'] = 'warning';
        $_SESSION['msg']['content'] = 'An error occurred while saving product from line '.($i+1).'. Please fix errors and try again.';
        if(DEBUG){
            $log = fopen(LOG_FILE, 'a');
            fwrite($log, date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Failed to insert product in file products.php Line 172. Error: ".$insertProduct->error."\n");
        }
        $break = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($line[0])` gives you what?

Comment: Shouldn't `bind_param()` be in the while loop?

Comment: This is for one of the lines `string(9) "Product 254"`

Comment: I'm new to this and I read in a few different places that you can bind once, out of loop. Should I try with it inside the loop?

Comment: Well, since you are changing the value of `$line` inside the loop, that would seem like a good idea

Comment: Btw, with that many parameters, it would be more legible/maintainable to bind them as named parameters

Comment: @Mawg with **mysqli?**

Comment: It works inside the loop. Thanks @Akintunde007

Comment: oops!! My bad. Just another reason to use PDO ;-)

Comment: Then  @Akintunde007 can post an answer, and you can accept it.

Comment: `bind_param()` binds to references, but maybe references to array indexes don't work. It will work if you bind to ordinary variables.